# SeparatedListAdapter only showing Headers

Tags: android, listadapter

For some reason when I view my list I only get the headers. I'm sure that the array that I'm using has data in it because the debug shows that it does.

Here's my SeparatedListAdapter file

```
public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public final Map<String,Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String,Adapter>();
public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;
public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;

public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context) {
    headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);
}

public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {
    this.headers.add(section);
    this.sections.put(section, adapter);
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section 
        if(position == 0) return section;
        if(position < size) return adapter.getItem(position - 1);

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
    }
    return null;
}

public int getCount() {
    // total together all sections, plus one for each section header
    int total = 0;
    for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
        total += adapter.getCount() + 1;
    return total;
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections
    int total = 1;
    for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
        total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
    return total;
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int type = 1;
    for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section 
        if(position == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
        if(position < size) return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
        type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
    }
    return -1;
}

public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int sectionnum = 0;
    for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section 
        if(position == 0) 
            return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
        if(position < size)
            return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
        sectionnum++;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

}

When I view the list it just shows the headers and nothing else.

**EDIT: Okay, so I figured it out and until I can self answer I'll just have to post the answer like this for now**

I figured out what I was doing. In my fragment I was clearing the ArrayList after I added the section, thinking that it wouldn't matter. Apparently it did matter.

Old Code

```
adapter.addSection(date, new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, taskArray));
    taskArray.clear();
```

New Code

```
adapter.addSection(date, new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, new ArrayList<String>(taskArray)));
    taskArray.clear();
```

Adding `new ArrayList<String>(taskArray)` to the `addSection` call resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing. In my fragment I was clearing the ArrayList after I added the section, thinking that it wouldn't matter. Apparently it did matter.

Old Code

`adapter.addSection(date, new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, taskArray));
    taskArray.clear();`

New Code

`adapter.addSection(date, new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, new ArrayList<String>(taskArray)));
    taskArray.clear();`

Adding new ArrayList(taskArray) to the addSection call resolved my issue.